# not able to filter the individual column in datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am new in jQuery facing issue while using column filter in Datatable my code is as follows

```
table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;

  $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
      that.search(this.value).draw();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm getting this error while filtering in the column:

> table.columns(...).every is not a function

I am using this https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: Have you initialized the table?

Comment: yes ....initialization is as follows
 var table = $('#tblWBSConstraint').DataTable({ "sDom": "ti", paging: false });

Comment: Please add your HTML code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed your code snippets here: http://live.datatables.net/jaxojugo/1/edit

It works without error.  Are you initializing DT before using "table.columns().every()"?